# svn authentication from cron job (osx 10.7)

Tags: svn, authentication, cron

I setup a crontab entry to pull code from an svn repo - I've done this before, so not sure what I missed this time.  It's on OSX 10.7 (Lion).

If the repo is public, it works without problem.

If the repo is private (i.e. requires user/pass), the authetication fails, even though my credentials are cached since normally I can do this at the command line without a user/pass prompt.

The email generated by cron tells me I'm running the same shell, am the same user, the home folder is correct, etc.  But svn fails to export the file; I can see in the error cron emails me that it asks for a password, doesn't get it, asks then for user, doesn't get it, and finally fails with the message:

authorization failed: Could not authenticate to server: rejected Basic challenge 
(I've omitted the specific URLs)

I have tried the --non-interactive and --config-dir options with no luck, though I've never had to do this before.

Ideas?

thanks, thomas blom in austin, tx

Comment: Just side idea: maybe you'll enable verbose output, redirect stderr to log and it will give you|us some food? For http-based repo: "To get more verbose output for subversion operations, you have to enable 
neon debug in the client. edit the ~/.subversion/servers file by adding the 
line `neon-debug-mask = 130`  to the [global] section of 
the file, making sure that you also uncomment the [global] line as well."

Comment: Possibly related topic (without accepted answer) [http://serverfault.com/questions/293835/svn-command-works-in-shell-but-not-in-cron-why-not](http://serverfault.com/questions/293835/svn-command-works-in-shell-but-not-in-cron-why-not)

Comment: This is the same issue on a different forum; a user there posts how to fix this for ssh-agent, but I'm not sure how to apply this to svn.  Unfortunately it sounds like the answer is "use launchctl".  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/18832/ssh-under-cron-stops-working-in-os-x-10-7-lion

Answer (score 2):

`svn help co`

```
Global options:
  --username ARG           : specify a username ARG
  --password ARG           : specify a password ARG
```

Comment: While this does actually work, it also seems to require that I allow svn to store the passwords unencrypted to disk, and is not a good solution since it means I have to store username and pass in the cronjob etc.  Normally if you have cached credentials, you don't have to explicitly provide this information -- and I don't have to provide it if I'm at a command prompt, only if it is being run from a cron job.

Comment: @ThomasBlom - maybe *personal crontab* will be solution for you?

Comment: @ThomasBlom and **you can** use --config-dir for auth purposes, but cashed authentication  from from is more correct direction, I think

Comment: Yes, I tried the --config-dir with no luck.  This is some OSX Lion issue, not a general svn issue.  See this link describing in detail the same kind of issue with ssg-agent.  http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/39614

Answer (score 0):

Try this... though I admit is very stupid, but it worked for me.

I use a dummy account to do my SVN / Cron work, and I recently ran into the same thing you are. OSX Lion.

I can run the command on the command line, but not through cron. I can't explain it, because I am in a hurry where I am at actually, so I leave the research to you'al. Here is what I did to fix my issue:

1. Remotely sign in to your account using SSH
2. Recursively remove ~/Library/Keychains
3. While still remotely loged in, perform your svn command (I have the settings in my ~/.subversion/servers to save passwords etc etc just FYI)

This worked for me. For some reason, Mac's Keychain was interfering with subversion's built-in save_my_authentication method, as I could see an entry for my LDAP/SVN command in Keychains. But Keychains doesn't seem to use it through Cron, or... cron doesn't use Keychains :) (probably true that last part)

Obviously, if this is your personal account, you probably don't want to delete the Keychain directory! You might try deleting the SVN entry within the Keychain only, then performing the SVN command while remote'd in using SSH.